# c# linq join on multiple attributes with different names

Tags: c#, .net, linq

trying to do a linq join on two attributes where the attributes have different names I am receiving.

> The type of one of the expressions in the join clause is incorrect
>   type inference failed on the call to join

here is the fiddle https://dotnetfiddle.net/xKg9mB

here is the code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace linq2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<MyClass1> list1 = new List<MyClass1>() { new MyClass1() { thing1 = "hello", thing2 = "world" } };
            List<MyClass2> list2 = new List<MyClass2>() { new MyClass2() { thing3 = "hello", thing4 = "world" } };

            var bothLists = from l1 in list1
                            join l2 in list2 on new { l1.thing1, l1.thing2 } equals new { l2.thing3, l2.thing4 }
                            select new
                            {
                                thing1 = l1.thing1,
                                thing2 = l1.thing2
                            };

            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        }
    }

    public class MyClass1
    {
        public string thing1 { get; set; }
        public string thing2 { get; set; }
    }

    public class MyClass2
    {
        public string thing3 { get; set; }
        public string thing4 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just rename the attributes in the query's join clause:

```
from l1 in list1
join l2 in list2 
on new { a = l1.thing1, b = l1.thing2 } equals new { a= l2.thing3, b = l2.thing4 }
select new
{
      thing1 = l1.thing1,
      thing2 = l1.thing2
 };
```

This will resolve the problem.